# Cordova File API on Android: window.requestFileSystem never fire on device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to develop a simple app on android.
I'm using Angular js and Cordova Visual studio. 
I need to save some data(a simple xml) for persisting data, for later use.
The only solution i founded is use the cordova file api.

I added the API on PhoneGap Build(plugins panel) and tried to use the code in the documentation in a empty project for learning but...on the device the code never fire anything, i tried to add some dialogs on success or fail code but they never get fired.
Then I tried to fire the  window.requestFileSystem on a button but still nothing happens. The command is likely ignored and i'm stuck on this from days.

Some other useful information:

- I used the dialogs api and it worked like a charm, so seems i was capable to install correctly the plugins from the PhoneGap Build.
- On ripple emulator that code always fire me an error, but seems you cant test that api on the emulator.

  There is the code that i'm trying to get work:

  ```
  // Wait for device API libraries to load
  //
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  // device APIs are available
  //
  function onDeviceReady() {
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
  }

  function gotFS(fileSystem) {
      fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
  }

  function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
  }

  function gotFile(file){
      readDataUrl(file);
      readAsText(file);
  }

  function readDataUrl(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          console.log("Read as data URL");
          console.log(evt.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  function readAsText(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          console.log("Read as text");
          console.log(evt.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  function fail(error) {
      console.log(error.code);
  }

  </script>
  ```

instead of the console log in the device i added pop up dialogs...but they never get fired, not in success and not in the fail.

What i'm doing wrong?

Any help it will be appreciated!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure the path for "readme.txt" isn't wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are adding proper storage access permission in Android Manifest file. Please go through the webpage : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and add permission to Manifest file

e.g

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: That was i 'm missing, now istructions show me dialogs, and i can continue the learning process! Thank you a lot for the help!!!!

Via Phone GAP you can change the manifest on the config.xml...adding this line :
 <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  </gap:config-file>

Answer (score 0):

You could use html5 `localstorage` to save/load your xml string, its very simple and straightforward to implement.

to store use:

```
// Store
localStorage.xml= "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";
```

and to retrive you can easily use:

```
// Retrieve
var yourXML = localStorage.xml;
```

and then use `jQuery.parseXML(yourXML)` to parse your xml string.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( yourXML ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
// Append "Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
```

Comment: The storage will persist after the turn off of the app?